# Dynamic Data Masking performance overhead

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dynamic-data-masking

I'm thinking of using the new dynamic data masking that has been introduced with SQL Server 2016 as part of our GDPR project . Does anyone else have experience of it? I am particularly interested if there is a performance overheard.

Comment: This [article](https://dbafromthecold.com/2016/04/13/sql-2016-dynamic-data-masking/) will give you head start about writing your own test harness.

Comment: Also see [Understand the Limitations of SQL Server Dynamic Data Masking](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4002/understand-the-limitations-of-sql-server-dynamic-data-masking/) - this doesn't address performance, but might identify potential issues with this technology that you haven't considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no overhead involved (not heard of any yet). I have used it in my Azure SQL Database and works like a charm.

Data Masking is a quick solution for data security as you can control the users who can view the data, but on a broader aspect this cannot be the sole security solution.

Please read below links for better understanding:

1. [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking) (Microsoft documentation)
2. [Encrypting SQL Server: Dynamic Data Masking](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/encrypting-sql-server-dynamic-data-masking/) by Robert Sheldon

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm aware its a bit of a quick fix but we are looking at other options. We decided on this route because we felt column level encryption wasn't an option